# Ask Location & Storage permission again in Android

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions, permission-denied

I'm building my android app with minimum `api level 23`. My app requires `storage(READ/WRITE)` and current location permission. When user access has been denied 2 times, then the dialog box is not popping up again.

I want to show the popup again & again instead of sending user to app-info to give permission manually after denying. Is that possible?

My Storage permmision code:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

        

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2);

            }
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2);
          
            }
   

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 2: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

My Location permission code:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
 this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
}



@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == 1){
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
           Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. You should display some popup informing the user that your app requires this permission and then after clicking a positive button you should move the user to the app settings.

The reason for that is after denying permission twice the status is set for "denied forever" and the `ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, permission)` method will return false.

Some apps force users to give permission by disabling a particular feature of the app. For example, after clicking "show on the map" button just request permission and in case of denial show a popup that the app requires this permission and the user can't open the map view.